# GASにて、GoogleカレンダーAPIより、イベントの主催者のEmailを取得する方法

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

GASにて、GoogleカレンダーAPIより、イベントの作成者はgetCreators()メソッドで取得できるようですが、イベントの主催者を取得するメソッドは無さそうです。
その場合、イベントの主催者を取得するにはどのようにGASにてコーディングしますでしょうか。

厳密には、イベントの主催者のEmailを取得したいです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
まだまだGASの知見が浅く、GASの実装が解らなかったのですよね。。。

Answer (score 0):

GAS での実装は分かりませんが、リファレンスを見る限り `Events` メソッドの結果からプロパティの `organizer.email` を参照すればよさそうです。

https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events?hl=ja#resource